# Heroku Postgres based api set up error 503

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I am trying to create a very simple todo app with PERN stack, but for the API I created which works fine on local environment, it keeps giving me the 503 error when I try to call it with a get request. I am not sure where to start debugging. The fetch request from my ListTodos.js from my react front end seems to be unable to call the API.

I think it is some postgres setup on heroku error but I am unsure.